# Google Play store showing updates after several weeks?

Tags: google-play-store, updates

[image: A]

Se the screenshot above. When I check for updates, Play store shows some updates that has been available for a few days, or even a few weeks. However when I was checking a few hours/days earlier, it did not show up. This means Play is postponing some updates. Why does this happen? Is there any way I can always get the latest updates as soon as they're published?

Comment: Some phones get a specific update later then others. So it could be that your phone gets them late. Check in gboard's "read more" option and it will tell you when it was last updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it says under Gboard "Updated 4 weeks ago", it means that the last time you updated the app was 4 weeks ago, and not that a new update was available 4 weeks ago.

My proof?
The Chinese app that appears under Gboard was never updated by you.
It should have also ben said "Updated x days ago".

And look at Google app under that, you updated it 3 min ago and not that Google pushed out an update 3 min ago.

Comment: Brilliant observation!

Comment: +1. I agree. For evidence, here are three screenshots. Play Store shows YouTube was updated [*three* weeks ago](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZPPZ.png), but under YouTube page's Read More, the last update by developer was [five days ago](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CC30d.png), on Nov 21, 2017. Now, I last updated my YouTube app on [Nov 5, 2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Do5eX.png), which by today's date make up for three weeks, hence, the answer is correct.

Comment: This is definately not correct. You can see on the apps individual listing page when it's last update was released. There is indeed a huge lag between when the app gets updated, and when the Play Store realizes that you have an app to update.